# Blossom Algorithm

Tags: matching

I have noticed that in the blossom algorithm, we need to find the blossom while finding the augmenting path. What will happen if I just know there is a blossom in a graph and the contracted graph has an augmenting path. Will the original graph not have that augmenting path or will be same?